# How do I hide/show in next/previous elements?

Tags: javascript, html, sass

I'm currently working on a project here:
https://github.com/Huy-jpg/images-transition

And I need help on how to have only one image have a bigger size than the other.
The function I wrote keep giving "cannot read classList of null".

Here's the js:

```
const images = document.querySelectorAll('.images'),
      headings = document.querySelectorAll('.heading');

images.forEach(image =>{
  image.addEventListener('click', (e) =>{
    image.classList.toggle('box-active')

    if(e.target === image.firstElementChild){
      if(image.nextElementSibling.classList.contains('box-active')){
        image.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('box-active')
      }
    }
    if(e.target === image.lastElementChild){
      if(image.previousElementSibling.classList.contains('box-active')){
        image.previousElementSibling.classList.remove('box-active')
      }
    }

    // headings.forEach(heading =>{
    //   heading.classList.toggle('letter-active')
    // })
  })
})
```

Comment: Can you please post the html that goes along with this?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem appears to be that you are comparing the wrong divs. This will break for example, when you click on the last image. It will throw that error because it matches `e.target === image.firstElementChild` but there is no `image.nextElementSibling`.

Ex:

```
// index.html
...
<div className="images last-img">
  <img
    src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1755243/pexels-photo-1755243.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-zhaocan-li-1755243.jpg&fm=jpg"
    alt="snow mountain"
    height="700"
    className="picture"
  />
  <h1 className="heading4 heading">Snow Mountain</h1>
</div>
```

and

```js
       if (e.target === image.firstElementChild) {
          console.log(
            e.target,
            image.firstElementChild,
            image.nextElementSibling
          );

          if (image.nextElementSibling.classList.contains("box-active")) {
            image.nextElementSibling.classList.remove("box-active");
          }
        }
```

In this case, `image` is the div wrapping the actual image. When you check the case `e.target === image.firstElementChild` that matches because the `firstElementChild` is the actual `img` tag. The problem is that `image.nextElementSibling` is null because the `image` div has no other sibling after it.

[example in react codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/httpsstackoverflowcomquestions65572312how-do-i-hide-show-in-next-previous-elements-1fxww?file=/src/App.jsx)